# In C# label.Update() does not work, but textbox.Update() does?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

So I am doing a somewhat lengthy progress in another class, and I want to give some progress info to my GUI.  I am aware of background worker, and may use it for this if I HAVE to, but this operation is so simple that I feel that background worker is a bit more than I need.  Instead, I am using eventhandlers to handle the updates, but the operation is inconsistent.

When a point has been reached in the worker class, it puts up an event telling about its progress.  In the GUI class, I have an eventhandler listening for that event.  When it finds it, it makes a string about it, and puts that string as the text of a label.

I then call labelname.Update() in that eventhandler, but nothing happens.  Here's the really confusing part, I put a textbox there instead, set its text, and then called textboxname.Update(), and it worked.  Why would .Update() not work for one control, but not another.  Is there a trick to get it to work for a label?

Comment: what ui are you dealing with - winforms or wpf?

Comment: I am using Winforms for this GUI.

Comment: Could you try introducing an `Application.DoEvents()` call after setting the label’s text?

Comment: I know it is bad form, but I tried it to check as you requested.  It had the same effect.  Label does not update, but textbox still does.

Comment: Its not working because your event is on the same thread as your UI. Use a delegate on your eventhandler to write to your label.

Comment: If you're doing heavy work that demands progress updating, you need to do it off the UI thread.  Use a background worker, it's not as painful as your post makes it out to be.

Comment: What is "somewhat lengthy"?  Windows considers 5 seconds too long and will put up the ghost window.  Calling Update() won't have any effect after that.

Comment: What if you pass the label control by reference to your method and update it from within?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am turning Roken's comment into an answer, but his remark *is* the answer. You must implement the background operation in a background worker, period.

See [this excellent article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28485/Beginners-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-5-of-n) about the why and how.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Try to call [`labelname.Invalidate();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx) before calling `labelname.Update();`

> Calling the Invalidate method does not force a **synchronous** paint; to
>   force a synchronous paint, call the Update method after calling the
>   Invalidate method. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx))

(2) Another option is calling [`labelname.Refresh();`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx)

> Forces the control to invalidate its client area and **immediately**
>   redraw itself and any child controls. ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh.aspx))